# 'compareTo' comparison use case

Tags: java, collections

```
package Comparable;

public class Movie implements Comparable<Movie> {

    private double rating;
    private String name;
    private int year;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Movie m) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.year - m.year;
    }

    public Movie(double rating, String name, int year) {
        this.rating = rating;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
    }    
}
```

**Main class :**

```
package Comparable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ArrayList<Movie> list = new ArrayList<Movie>();
        list.add(new Movie(8.8, "Force Awakens", 2015));
        list.add(new Movie(7.7, "Star Wars", 1977));
        list.add(new Movie(9.9, "Empire Strikes back", 1980));
        list.add(new Movie(3.2, "Return of the jedi", 1983));

        // Sort the items based on the pararmeter mentioned in the compareTo method
        // .Here the sort pareameter is the year of the release.
        Collections.sort(list);

        System.out.println("Movie after sorting :"+"\n");
        for (Movie movie : list) {
            System.out.println(movie.getName() + " " + movie.getRating() + " " + movie.getYear());
        }
    }

}
```

I have the above use case of `compareTo` . I wanted to understand what the `compareTo` method is doing under the hood. When I override the `compareTo` method and decided to sort by 'year'; how is the comparison happening? I can understand that it returns `1`, `-1` and `0` according to the result of comparison. But how is the comparison happening in the below line of code:

```
 return this.year - m.year;
```

When I say `this.year`, is the code taking the first item i.e

```
8.8, "Force Awakens", 2015
```

and comparing to all of the elements of the list, i.e the elements of the `movie` object as passed into `compareTo` method above?

How is the object comparison happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class `Movie` has a `compareTo` method defined such that `this` Movie is considered "greater" than `other` Movie if `this` Movie was released in a later year than `other` Movie. 
If they came out in the same year, they are considered equal.
If `other` Movie came out later, it is considered "smaller".

### Example

Comparing Movies `this = (8.8, "Force Awakens", 2015)` and `other = (7.7, "Star Wars", 1977)`:

```
return this.year - other.year
return 2015 - 1977
return 38 // i.e. this > other
```

Note that if you reverse the movies, you get the opposite result, as you would expect for an ordering.

### Principle

So "under the hood", the program is able to deduce that

*(8.8, "Force Awakens", 2015) > (3.2, "Return of the jedi", 1983) > (9.9, "Empire Strikes back", 1980) > (7.7, "Star Wars", 1977)*

pretty much by sampling results for calling `compareTo` on various pairs of movies.
The exact implementation details of the sorting method, like the used algorithm don't particularly matter and this is abstracted away from you. The important part is that you make sorting possible by defining the natural ordering, i.e. making the program able to consistently decide for any pair of `Movie` objects which one of the two is "greater".

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) the documentation of `Collections.sort(..)` method, this is what it says:

> Sorts the specified list into ascending order, according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface. Furthermore, all elements in the list must be mutually comparable (that is, e1.compareTo(e2) must not throw a ClassCastException for any elements e1 and e2 in the list).

And this is how the sorting is done:

> This implementation dumps the specified list into an array, sorts the
>   array, and iterates over the list resetting each element from the
>   corresponding position in the array. This avoids the n2 log(n)
>   performance that would result from attempting to sort a linked list in
>   place.

So Yes, so you are right. It picks up each element from the list and compares it with other elements using `compareTo`.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Just think of something like bubble sort, each element is compared with other elements and then their positions are exchanged if they are in wrong order. Here `compareTo` is being used to make that comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the input.